# WebView kotlin upload file camera and storage

Tags: android, webview, kotlin

I have a webview that works with uploading files from the SD, but I haven't been able to get the upload to ask me if it's by camera or SD.

Look for examples of java the only simple and functional one but I didn't manage to migrate it to kotlin

[example webview upload file](https://github.com/chiclaim/android-webview-upload-file)

```
            //For Android5.0+
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                    WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                    FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
                    mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
                }
                mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback;

                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    // Create the File where the photo should go
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try {
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        // Error occurred while creating the File
                        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
                    }

                    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    } else {
                        takePictureIntent = null;
                    }
                }

                Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");

                Intent[] intentArray;
                if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                } else {
                    intentArray = new Intent[0];
                }

                Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);

                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQUEST_CODE_LOLIPOP);

                return true;
            }
});
```

I have an error in getActivity(), tryArray = new Intent[0];, which I can't resolve.

BIG THANKS

Comment: Where are you calling `getActivity()`, `tryArray = new Intent[0];`, and what is the error being thrown?

Comment: - if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null)

```None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public open fun getActivity(p0: Context!, p1: Int, p2: Intent!, p3: Int): PendingIntent! defined in android.app.PendingIntent
public open fun getActivity(p0: Context!, p1: Int, p2: Intent!, p3: Int, p4: Bundle!): PendingIntent! defined in android.app.PendingIntent```


- intentArray = arrayOfNulls<Intent>(0)

```Type mismatch: inferred type is Array<Intent?> but Array<Intent> was expected
```

Comment: Try putting `!!` after your `getActivity()` so it doesn't return a nullable and for the second one use `arrayOf<Intent>()` for the same reason.

Comment: UPDATE:
1. getActivity().getPackageManager() --> this@MyActivity.getPackageManager()
2. intentArray = new Intent[0]; --> intentArray = arrayOf<Intent>()

Thanks urgentx